# Make everything Centralise with my title div

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, center

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/index.html
As you will see when you resize the browser everything does centralise until the browser edge touches the main div and then only the navigation bar stays centralised.
I know this is a problem with my coding, but I cant find the problem.
here is the css as well
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/main.css

thanks in advance
Arran, 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your stylesheet just make the below edit, please find it below :-

```
#main {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099FF;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 3px #000000;
    height: 1600px;
    left: 0; /* right: 20px; this has been changed to 0;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* right: 20px; this has been changed to 0;*/
    top: 0;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Edit - The explanation:**

As you have given the right and left value to `20px` hence its forcing the `<div id="main">` to move `20px` from left side. Thats the reson a `20px` space was generating while you were resizing the browser to fit the div.

Comment: thank you very much that worked. Also what do you think about my site. any changes to make it look better. please me as critical as you like

Comment: I found that you have used position absolute to place elements. Any specific reason to use them? Actually you shouldn't use position if not needed.

Comment: ok. and visually does the site attract you. or should i change the boxes colours ect.

Comment: As per me the design is not attractive, you should change it.

Comment: You should go through the websites here, http://www.cssmania.com/ and see how the designs are looking and then accumulate some idea and create a design.

Comment: @ Subhajit I did change it and personaly i think it is better